# Unable to send TFS credentials

Tags: tfs

I am trying to send TFS credentials to the server for connecting TFS server using below code

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer().
```

This method is expecting two input parameters.one is of type string(tfs url as string) and another one is of type `ICredentialsProvider`.I am unable to create instance of this class and unable to send TFS credentials to `Getserver` method.Please help me if any body has idea about it.

Thanks
Suneetha.

Answer (score 5):

What sort of errors are you getting when you create an `ICredentialsProvider`?

You should be able to instantiate a `UICredentialsProvider` object that implements `ICredentialsProvider`.

Alternatively you can construct a `TeamFoundationServer` instance and pass credentials through the constructor.

These links might help:

- [Connect to TFS](http://www.tfsexamples.com/Default.aspx?Page=Connect%20to%20TFS)
- [TFS API: How to choose between TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer() and the TeamFoundationServer constructor](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/comments/755115.aspx)
- [How to get the login dialog when using the Team Foundation Server API](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2006/03/17/credentialprovider.aspx)

Comment: Hi 

I am using this method to get version control serevr.

            NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(AppSettings.Username, AppSettings.Password, AppSettings.Domain);
            ICredentials ICP = (ICredentials)creds;
            TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(AppSettings.TfsUrl, ICP);
            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
            return tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;

I am able to connect now but it is returning versioncontrolserver  as null.

Thanks
suneetha

Comment: Hi Suneetha. I can't see any problem in the code. Perhaps the URL is incorrect? Are you including the port number for TFS (8080 by default for HTTP connections)? Example: "http://tfs.dev.company.com:8080". You could change the last line to "return (VersionControlServer) tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer))" which will throw an exception if the cast fails. This might help uncover any casting errors. Otherwise perhaps the user does not have access to the version control system in TFS?

Comment: A small point: The line "ICredentials ICP = (ICredentials)creds;" is unnecessary: you can just pass the variable "creds" to the TeamFoundationServer constructor instead of "ICP" since NetworkCredential implements ICredentials.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkCredential networkCredential;

```
        if (Username != null && Password != null)
        {
             if (Domain != null)
                  networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, Domain);
             else
                  networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
         }
         else
         {
              networkCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
         }


        TeamFoundationServer TFS = new TeamFoundationServer( stringTFSURL, networkCredentials);
```